# Sell by unity and weight - Shopify

Tags: shopify

I need something similar to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrPhz.png)

So if the client wants to buy one onion or 1kg of onion he can choose how to buy it.
How can I add it?

I'm not a code expert! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it logically. You can prompt the user to add any number of onion he wants and give him the option to go to the checkout to buy or keep shopping.

Here is the pseudocode

```
public int onion = 0;
Total_onion = user.add(onion);

if user is done shopping
  proceed to checkout 
else
    keep shopping
```

What programming language are you using?

Comment: It's from Shopify (product-template.liquid) so, liquid?  I figured out how to add the Weight and Quantity options however they are not related to each others so when I try to buy let's say 344g (2 bananas) when I go to the cart and I change the quantity let's say to 3 bananas the weight doesn't change. And the cost just adds up. As you can see I'm lost hahaha.  This is the page: https://dailymarket.mx/products/platano-dominico?variant=35874897068190